SSO session idle in Keycloak is not refreshed by the activity user
I have app in PHP where I use keycloak to authenticate, after that I have feature which check if access token doesn't expire. If access token expired, another function send request to keykloak to refresh toke and it is works too.
I have an issue with SSO Session Idle because I have set time by 10 minutes and Access Token Lifespan by 2 minut. In events I see information about refresh token every 2 minutes and in session I see change time in last access but I don't know why session always expire after time which is set in SSO Session Idle.

SSO Session Idle is only one factor in determining how long an SSO session is valid for, there are multiple different factors at play. For example:

How long is your SSO Session Max set to?
How long is your refresh token valid for?
Are refresh tokens set for single use?

There are also config overrides per client that can be determining factors.

Keycloak is latest release 25.0.5. Below realm configuration. Client inherits from realm. I didn't set refresh token. Refresh token is automatic when access token is expire.
SSO Session Idle: 10 minutes
SSO Session Max: 1 hour
Access Token Lifespan: 5 minutes

It sounds like your configuration is different to what you state in the question then. Can you update the question with the info you shared in the comment? You should be able to see the refresh token lifespan in the refresh token itself. Again, can you confirm if you are getting new refresh tokens each time or if you save the one token and keep re-using it?

For the test I set below parametrs.
SSO Session Idle - 5 minutes
SSO Session Max - 10 hours
Access Token Lifespan - 1 minutes
Every request on my app check validy access token. If access token is expired then refresh token via refresh token get new access token and events in keycloak shows generation refresh token.

Great, that's helpful, and as a rule of thumb with Stack Overflow, it's also helpful to update your question with any additional context from the comments here. I think the main question I'm still not sure of the answer is:
can you confirm if you are getting a new refresh tokens each time or if you save the one token and keep re-using it? That needs to be answered from both the Keycloak side and the application side too.
